# Question about high level architecture required to process and visualize fitness app data (From Apple Health for example) using google cloud services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a project where I am tasked to use google cloud services to process and visualize fitness data. For example, I have exported some apple health data from my watch, and it is in .xml format. From a high level, I envision this .xml file starting off in object storage, and being converted to .csv through a cloud function (triggered by the creation of the .xml object in storage) and stored again in object storage (different bucket). Then I see these .csv files being processed by a DataFlow pipeline, which will reformat the data to the template schema that I would like the data to be organized with. This pipeline will output the resultant .csv to BigQuery, which will then be designated as a data source for Data Studio. I will then configure Data Studio to produce some simple reports that compare the health data to recommended values. I would like for this report to be accessible as a .pdf in object storage potentially as well. Am I on the right track, or am I missing some key services to accomplish this?

Also, I'm new to posting on StackOverflow, so if this question is against the rules or not welcome, please let me know.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated, as I have not been able to bounce these ideas off of other experienced cloud architects/developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is currently off-topics by the rule of [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as it does not contain any problems to resolve. See point 4-5.

As a high-level advice, I do not see why it should not be possible based on the services you mentioned but you would need to implement it and try it on your side and evaluate the features of each service in your workflow.

In terms of solution or architecture advice, those are generally paid services and you would most likely find little help here for those unless you have a specific problem to solve with said services. You might find some help on the internet as well. ie.[Cloud Solutions](https://gcp.solutions/), [Built it on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/docs/#build-it-on-gcp), etc

You might find [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-gaming-analysis-telemetry) interesting to review as well as it mimics your solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing that out. I will make sure there is an actual problem to resolve moving forward.

Comment: Also, Thank you for the resources! They are very helpful and honestly they answer my very broad/general questions